# SQLite Database - RESET information

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile, android-sqlite

I'm currently making a code that uses a database. This is the class of the database:

```
public class ScriptDLL {

public static String getCreateTableCliente(){
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CLIENTE (");
    sql.append("       CODIGO       INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,");
    sql.append("       NOME         VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),");
    sql.append("       ENDERECO     VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),");
    sql.append("       EMAIL        VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),");
    sql.append("       TELEFONE     VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL DEFAULT ('') )");
    return sql.toString();
}
```

}

Ok, so i want to make a SQLite code to set `CODIGO` back to `1`. How could i write this code?

Thanks!

Comment: if CODIGO is a column and you want to set all the values in this column to 1, you can try update statement: "UPDATE TABLE_NAME set  CODIGO=1"

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense.  CODIGO is the primary key.  It will increment by 1 for each item.  It will never go back to 1, even if you delete things, because that could cause it to violate its UNIQUE constraint.  The only way to make it go back to 1 is to delete the entire table and all data in it.

Comment: how could i delete the entire table and data in it?

Comment: Your recent SO activity tells me you have no experience in Databases nor a proper or minimal education about them. This is not an adequate place to learn by asking whatever obstacle you run into when developing software without basic knowledge or experience. I strongly suggest you first go through the basics of what you are trying to achieve with tutorials and some sort of teaching.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to increment the version by 1 and the old table is dropped and new table is created, this will avoid failure due to uniqueness constraint if records already exist in the table(you take care of migration ofcourse). If you have specific need just to reset codigo then try the below code. It resets the value to 1 in the internal sqllite record `SQLITE_SEQUENCE`.

Refer documentation which explains more about autoincrement and `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` : https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

```
public static String resetKey(){
return "UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 1 WHERE name = CLIENTE";
}
```

Comment: how do i drop the old table and create a new one?

Comment: @VandervalBorgesDeSouzaJuni You should have a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. In constructor of this class one of the parameter is the version, just increment it by one. You can post the code and I can help

Comment: If i increment the version mannualy it doesn't gets the "CODIGO" back to 1.

Comment: @Psypher Setting seq to 1 will mean that the next insert (if there are no other rows in the table) using a value of at least 2 for the column. You would have to set it to 0 for the column to have 1 (true reset).

Comment: @VandervalBorgesDeSouzaJuni Thats right. Set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a one-off then just Delete the App's data, or uninstall the App and rerun.

If you want to do this frequently (ignoring the fact that relying upon the column being specific values most likely indicates a flaw in the design) then:-

You could DROP and recreate the table as is often done in the `onUpgrade` method of the Database Helper. Doing this in the `onUpgrade` method could be problematic/complicated if you had multiple tables and potentially even more complicated if you had multiple versions.

You could have a specific method such as :-

```
public void resetCODIGO() {
    this.getWritableDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CLIENTE;");
    this.getWritableDatabase.execSQL(getCreateTableCliente());
}
```

- DROPing a table will result in the respective row in the **sqlite_sequence** table being deleted by SQLite.
- The sqlite_sequence table has a row per table that has a column with AUTOINCREMENT (only 1 allowed per table).

  - the sqlite_sequence table has two defined columns **name** for the table name and **seq** for the last inserted sequence number.

Another solution that would involve `DROP` and `CREATE` BUT does involve updating the **sqlite_sequence** table could be to delete all rows from the table and to then delete the respective row in the **sqlite_sequence** table.

Thus alternately you could have :-

```
public void resetCODIGO() {
    this.getWritableDatabase.delete("CLIENTE");
    String whereclause = "name=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{"CLIENTE"};
    this.getWritableDatabase.delete(
        "sqlite_sequence",
        whereclause,
        whereargs
    );
}
```

**Note** the above code is in-principle code and hasn't necessarily been tested, so it may contain some errors.